# Pass value to open cmd file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line-arguments

I need to run a cmd from a particular location in order to call another internal exe file.

Please find the details:
Cmd prompt should open with below path:

```
D:\program\ser\conf>
```

I have used this command:

```
cmd /k "cd /D D:\program\ser\conf"
```

Now, I need to pass the following arg for my requirement.

```
"D:\program\ser\int.exe" "D:\program\ser\conf\script.txt"
```

Comment: They didn't even _try_ to make a batch file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Now, I need to pass the below arg for my requirement.

Use the following batch file.

**test.cmd:**

```
cd /D D:\program\ser\conf
D:\program\ser\int.exe D:\program\ser\conf\script.txt
```